# db_affected_rows() return "1" when the query is wrong

Tags: 7, database

I have a query like `UPDATE user SET creator = 'creator'"`. The "user" table has not the "creator" column, so `db_affected_rows()` shoud return −1, not 1.

Why?

**Update**: `mysql_affected_rows()` returns -1 for this query. I created a "creator" column (unique); after I update the user table, I get the error "User warning: Duplicate entry," but `db_affected_rows()` still returns 1.

Comment: just fyi: db_affected_rows() calls mysql_affected_rows() and not mysql_num_rows() - both both should return -1 when the query fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
db_affected_rows() returns an unexpected value because watchdog is turned on. I watched to see if there was another query after the one I ran and before my db_affected_rows() call, and sure enough:

> INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (1, 'php', '%message in %file on line %line.', 'a:4:{s:6:\"%error\";s:12:\"user warning\";s:8:\"%message\";s:104:\"Unknown column 'name2' in 'field list'\nquery: UPDATE users SET name2 = 'a'\"; [...]

So, db_affected_rows() is returning 1 because watchdog is logging an error. Thus, the proper way to see if a query had an error or not -- and count the rows affected if it *was* successful -- is:

```
$result = db_query("UPDATE users SET name2 = 'a'"); 
if ($result) {
  printf("Records affected: %d\n", db_affected_rows());
}
else {
  print "Query not successful";
}
```

Hope this helps!

---

*Original answer for posterity:*

I'd have to see the code around your query. Try running this:

```
<?php
function db_affected_rows() {
  global $link;
  return mysql_affected_rows($link);
}

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('d6.devl');

/* this should return the correct numbers of deleted records */
mysql_query("UPDATE user SET creator = 'creator'");
printf("Records affected: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());

printf("Records affected: %d\n", db_affected_rows());
```

I did and it worked alright:

> $ php -f test.php
>
> Records affected: -1
>
> Records affected: -1

Comment: after 2 days i see edited reply and one post in your blog :) .thank u so much Entendu

Answer (score 1):

Try to reproduce that outside of Drupal with just `mysql_query()`, `mysql_affected_rows()` and so on.

This might be an issue with your PHP version or something like that. Drupal just passes the call forward, it doesn't do anything ony it's own.

Comment: thank u. please check this code it return a error and "1" <?php db_query("UPDATE users SET name2 = 'a'"); printf("Records affected: %d\n", db_affected_rows());

Comment: Wow, that does return "1". I'm digging in and will update my answer.

Comment: K, figured it out.